# Getting "Error establishing a database connection" on local wamp, when not connected to Internet

Tags: wordpress, netbeans, localhost, wamp

I am using Netbeans IDE v8.2 & Wamp server v3.0.0 for my WordPress development.
It has never happened, however from recent when I am not connected to Internet, I am getting "Error establishing a database connection" error.

If connected to Internet, I am able to access WordPress on my local host.

While I googled this error, most of them are not related to my specific situation of, getting error while offline.

**wp-config.php**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'wordpress.dev');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I have defined the local domain in the `hosts` files as below:

```
127.0.0.1   www.wordpress.dev
```

Comment: This is on Windows 10.

Comment: Please provide your database connect information in wp-config.php

Comment: edited the question with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better that set your `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Your installation, or rather your wp-config.php, is pointing to a database that's not on your local machine. You need to change your db settings in wp-config.php.

Comment: www.wordpress.dev =/= wordpress.dev